# GWT String to date - month with 3 digits

Tags: java, gwt, datetime-format

I'm fairly new to GWT (2.3) and want to take an integer (or string) in the following format:

2012006

and format it to

1206

I know I can do it easily using string operations but as 2012 is the year and 006 is the month (June) I'm trying to do it using GWT DateTimeFormat but am struggling with the ridiculous 3-digit month format...

Pls help

./CJ

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy'0'MM");
Date date = fmt.parse("2012006");
```

to parse a String with the format you described into a date.

Use

```
DateTimeFormat out = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyMM");
out.format(date);
```

to format the date into the desired format.

Additional Parsing Considerations ([DateTimeFormat])[1](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

> When parsing a date string using the abbreviated year pattern ( "yy"), the parser must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the parser instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a DateTimeFormat object created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964.

Comment: Hmm... I keep getting a 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2012006

I'm trying to create a getMyDateFormatted as a @Transient method in my entity to be able to print a formatted date on my web page.

I have tried entering your code exactly as show and importing java.util.Date but all in vain :-(

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your code and a few more details about the exception?

Comment: Indeed, this error is due to a bug in GWT's DateTimeFormat parsing that does not handle numeric characters like '0' in between numeric patterns.

Comment: Went for the string operation instead - thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use quotes to interpret the first 0 as a literal. Try the following:

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy'0'MM")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will get your desired result

```
public class DateWala {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYMM").format(new Date()));
    }

}
```